Mode expansions of canonical quantized fields in QFT
I have been self-studying QFT Quantum Field Theory for the Gifted Amateur by Stephen Blundell and Tom Lancaster. They devote Chapters 11, 12, 13 to the subject of canonically quantizing any given field theory. I am quite confused about the entire procedure and I was hoping I could get some help here in understanding it. My main confusion is regarding the mode expansion of the field and making it satisfy the commutator relations we impose on the field and its conjugate momenta.
Background
For instance in Chapter 13 they provide an example of a theory with 3 scalar fields and a Lagrangian density,
$$\mathcal{L}= \dfrac{1}{2}\partial^{\mu}\boldsymbol{\Phi}\partial_{\mu}\boldsymbol{\Phi}-\dfrac{m^2}{2}\boldsymbol{\Phi}\cdot \boldsymbol{\Phi}$$
where $\boldsymbol{\Phi}=(\phi_1, \phi_2, \phi_3)$. The commutators of the quantized field are set to be $[\hat{\phi}_{\alpha}(t, \vec{x}), \hat{\Pi}^0_{\beta}(t, \vec{x})]=i\delta(\vec{x}-\vec{y})\delta_{\alpha\beta}$. Here $\hat{\Pi}^0_{\beta}(t, \vec{x})=\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_0 \phi_{\beta})}$ is the conjugate momenta. The mode expansion of this field operator is given as,
$$\hat{\boldsymbol{\Phi}}(x)= \int_p 
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{a}_{p1} e^{-ip\cdot x}+ \hat{a}^{\dagger}_{p1} e^{ip\cdot x}\\
\hat{a}_{p2} e^{-ip\cdot x}+ \hat{a}^{\dagger}_{p2} e^{ip\cdot x}\\
\hat{a}_{p3} e^{-ip\cdot x}+ \hat{a}^{\dagger}_{p3} e^{ip\cdot x}\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $\displaystyle \int_p= \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^{\frac{3}{2}}(2E_p)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ and $\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{p\lambda}$ and $\hat{a}_{p\lambda}$ are creation and annihilation operators for a particle with momentum $p$ in the field $\phi_{\lambda}$.
However in the next subsection they take another example of quantizing a massive theory of electromagnetism with the Lagrangian density,
$$\mathcal{L}= -\dfrac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}+ \dfrac{1}{2}m^2A_{\mu}A^{\mu}$$
The quantized fields are made to follow the commutator $[\hat{A}^{i}(t, \vec{x}), \hat{E}^j(t, \vec{x})]=-i\delta(\vec{x}-\vec{y})\eta^{ij}$ where $\eta^{ij}$ is the Minkowski metric and $\hat{E}^j(t, \vec{x})= \dfrac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_0 A_{i})}$ is the conjugate momenta. Here they only consider the spatial components of $\hat{A}^{\mu}$ since it is shown that $\hat{A}^0$ is non dynamical i.e. $\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_0 A_{0})}=0$.
Question
Now my question is, they used a different mode expansion in this case for the field operator $\hat{A}^{\mu}$ and I do not understand why. They have,
$$\hat{A}^{\mu}(x)= \int_p \sum_{\lambda=1}^3(\epsilon_{\lambda}^{\mu}(p)\hat{a}_{p\lambda} e^{-ip\cdot x}+ \epsilon_{\lambda}^{\mu *}(p)\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{p\lambda} e^{ip\cdot x})
$$
where $\epsilon_{\lambda}^{\mu}(p)$ is some polarization vector. I do not understand the need to introduce the vector nor do I get why we did not just use the same mode expansion from the 3 scalar field theory I described earlier. Both theories have 3 scalar fields, the one in the electromagnetism case just being the spatial components of the $\hat{A}^{\mu}$ operator. However we had a different expansion in each case. Why is that? How does one determine the mode expansion given the commutator relations?

"both theories have three scalar fields" -> This is not true. The components of vectors are not scalar, they change under coordinate transformation so that the whole vector is unchanged. The indices of the scalar field multiplet are not Lorentz indices, so the canonical choice of "polarization" multiplets is obvious.

But don't we have three degrees of freedom in both cases? In the textbook they eliminate $A^0$ using the condition $\partial_{\mu}A^{\mu}=0$ but we are free to set the spatial components of $A$ to whatever we want. So isn't that the same as in the 3-scalar field theory?

The two have three components but are completely different mathematical entities. Think of the vector as one unique object, and the multiplet of scalars as a bag containing 3 objects (as the notation you used for the field operator indicates).
